# Unable to access buckets in S3 using Zend S3.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I'm using Zend's S3 for accessing Amazon's cloud. The code looks like this:

```
require_once('Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php');
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3('ABCABVABC....', 'xF+5FxF+5FxF+5FxF+5FxF+5FxF+5FxF+5F');
$list = $s3->getBuckets();
```

But I get false, no buckets. However, if I use the same credentials and log in using a client like cyberduck, I got one bucket (which is correct) and within it all the contents I expect.

I've also tried to access the bucket directly with getObjectsByBucket('...'); which doesn't work either, I get false as well.

I'm not getting any exceptions or errors ... any ideas? Error reporting is turned up all the way.

Comment: I would suggest you use the new AWS SDK for PHP.. it is far more efficient than the Zend version.. http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue is that the server time was not accurate and that exception is not shown/thrown with Zend. Using another S3 library allowed me to see the exception, track it down and fix it.